# Get_header raises an 500 internal server error

Tags: theme-development, errors, template-tags

I am working on custom development in wordpress, my problem is the following every time I create a new template.

**Code**

```
 /* Template Name: Citas Rolex*/
 get_header();

echo "<h1>loren ipsum</h1>";

get_footer();
```

It gives me the following error in the user view

**In browser**

> Internal Server Error
>   The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>   Please contact the server administrator to inform of the time the error occurred and of anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

I miss that when I comment on `get_header ()` the view works perfectly for me

```
/* Template Name: Citas Rolex*/
//get_header();
 echo "<h1>loren ipsum</h1>";
  get_footer();
 ?>
```

Comment: Are you using an opening <?php tag?

Comment: How exactly are you using this template? If `get_header()` is causing a 500 error, it could mean that the function doesn't exist, because it's being accessed incorrectly. In that case `get_footer()` would also cause the exact same problem, but you wouldn't notice because it runs after your placeholder text.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create one template in WordPress, Please see below example

```
  <?php /* Template Name: CustomPageT1 */ 
    get_header();
    echo "hello this is my custom template";
    get_footer();
   ?>
```

Try this code.

Comment: I already have the template created, and it gives me error 500, but when I comment on get_header the error 500 is resolved, but on the get_header of all the menus. and if I don't have the get_header I can't use the headers I have for that headers. and I don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

I already have the template created, and it gives me error 500, but when I comment on get_header the error 500 is resolved, but on the get_header of all the menus. and if I don't have the get_header I can't use the headers I have for that headers. and I don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be overthinking this. Isn't the 500 error a page size issue? I get those issues in Elementor when there's too much on a page and the server times out. You need to adjust the php.ini file to increase size limit. We can explain that or you can do a simple google search but this needs to be done in a FTP transfer program like filezilla or cyberduck. Hope that helps

Comment: I am not using any page builder, I am doing it from scratch, as a base I am using underscores, the question is that when I comment the get_header (); the page if it goes well for me.